# AHK Script to Double-Click every X number of Left Clicks (Randomly Double-Click Every Couple Clicks)

Tags: automation, mouseevent, autohotkey

I was wondering if there was a way to write a AHK Script to Double-Click the left mouse button every random number of Left Clicks (Randomly Double-Click Every Couple Clicks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Absolutely

From [the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm), we have the `Random` function that

> Generates a pseudo-random number.

Using the syntax

> `Random, OutputVar , Min, Max`

Where `OutputVar` is the output variable, `Min` is the minimum value (inclusive), and `Man` is the manimum value (inclusive).

With this information, let's make a [subroutine](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm) called `generateNewRandom` that we can call every time every time we want to regenerate our random number.

For this example, I will set the `Min` to 1 and the `Max` to 10 so that a random number between `[1, 10]` inclusive is generated. You can change these values as needed.
We will save the output of the `Random` function into a variable named `NumClicks`.

---

Next, let's create a [hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) that will trigger every time the Left Mouse Button is clicked.

However, this hotkey will require several various [modifiers](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) (namely: *, ~, and $) in order to function properly. You can find out more about them in [the docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols).

In short:

- Wildcard (*) activates the hotkey even if other modifier keys (such as <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are held down
- Tilde (~) allows the hotkey's native function to still happen when the hotkey is triggered.
- Dollar Sign ($) allows a hotkey to [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) itself without causing an infinite loop.

For the hotkey itself, when LButton (The Left Mouse Button) is pressed, do the following:

- decrement numClicks
- if `numClicks` is 0

  - Click again
  - Generate a new Random number

---

In addition to the [Subroutine](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm) and the [Hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), we will need to call the [subroutine](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gosub.htm) once in the [auto-execute](https://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/auto-execute-section.html#:%7E:text=When%20an%20AutoHotkey%20script%20launches,called%20the%20auto%2Dexecute%20section.) section at the beginning in order to generate an initial random value.

---

### Final Script:

```
gosub generateNewRandom ;Generate initial random number

*~$LButton::
numClicks--
if(numClicks==0){
    Click
    gosub generateNewRandom ;Generate subsequent random numbers
}
return


generateNewRandom:
Random, numClicks , 1, 10 ;Adjust these values as needed
return
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Incredibly helpful :D
Cant believe you wrote out the entire script for me haha:D

Comment: No problem @Fxssil! I hope my explanation was easy enough to follow along; lmk if I should clarify anything